# Why do I still get duplicates on [CONMAT_MATCHING_DONOR] even after using DISTINCT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I still get duplicates on [CONMAT_MATCHING_DONOR] even after using `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [CONTRIB_MATCH_ID]
          ,[CONMAT_CONTRIBUTION]
          ,[CONMAT_FORM_RECEIVED_DATE]
          ,[CONMAT_MATCHING_DONOR]
          ,[CONMAT_STATUS]
          ,[STATUS_DESC]
          ,[CONMAT_STATUS_DATE]
      FROM [ods_production].[dbo].[SPT_CONTRIB_MATCH]
      WHERE  [CONMAT_MATCHING_DONOR] IN  (SELECT  DISTINCT   
            [CONMAT_MATCHING_DONOR]
            FROM [ods_production].[dbo].[SPT_CONTRIB_MATCH])
     ORDER BY [CONMAT_MATCHING_DONOR] DESC
```

Comment: try to add distinct in the outer query

Comment: Do you have any table info you can post? Also some results? What do you consider "duplicate"?

Comment: GROUP or PARTITION by that column.

Comment: With or without DISTINCT, your Where clause has no impact on the output of your query.  It will negatively impact the performance, though.  (With or without DISTINCT, your were clause subquery returns the entire set of [CONMAT_MATCHING_DONOR] in the table.  Then you restrict your main query to only those values...  which is every possible value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of `DISTINCT` in the `IN` clause doesn't make much sense - this will not affect the results of your query in any way.

Consider:

```
WITH v_base(name) AS (
  SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B')
SELECT name FROM v_base WHERE name IN (SELECT DISTINCT name from v_base)
```

which more or less translates to

```
WITH v_base(name) AS (
  SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B')
SELECT name FROM v_base WHERE name IN ('A', 'B')
```

vs

```
WITH v_base(name) AS (
  SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B')
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM v_base WHERE name IN (SELECT name from v_base)
```

which translates to

```
WITH v_base(name) AS (
  SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B')
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM v_base WHERE name IN ('A', 'A', 'B')
```

and the difference should become clear.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0be40/1)